# Jung2: NullPointerException "AWT-EventQueue-0" labelVertex(BasicVertexLabelRenderer.java:84)

Tags: jung2

When jung2 2.1 renders my graph in
rc.getVertexLabelTransformer().apply(v) (BasicRenderer.java, 74)
it takes my v object (not null, it has correct not null toString) and returns null that cause the exception in other place. How to fix it ?

PS I use Scala but doubt it affected. 
Code and report https://github.com/jrtom/jung/issues/60

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to move to 2.0.1 version because it is bug last 2.1 v. It seems nobody supports it now , better to use something else)

Comment: JUNG 2.1 is the only version that's currently supported.  Your problem report has been viewed, we just haven't had time to get to it yet (it's not my day job).  :)  Please follow the issue on GitHub.